# How to replace all underscores to spaces in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive

My Variable :

```
{{imageGrid.bannerName}}
```

My Output :

```
DINING_LANDING_PAGE_MEAL_PLAN_SUBSCRIBED_USER
```

How to replace _ in angularjs ?

Comment: Please remember to read [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Create a custom [**filter**](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_filters.asp) called `noUnderscore` and use it like so: `{{ imageGrid.bannerName | noUnderscore }}`

Comment: Makes sense @ibrahimmahrir so it's reusable

Comment: Do you mean angular (v2+) or angular.js (1.x)?  Its unclear because of your title, question, and tags.  The base javascript code will be the same which was already answered, but if you want to make a directive that is very different in Angular vs Angular.js

Answer (score 3):

Create a [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11) called, for example, `noUnderscore` like so:

```
/* the module you want to add this to */.filter("noUnderscore", function () {
    return function (input) {
        return input.replace(/_/g, " ");
    }
});
```

Then use it in your template like so:

```
{{ imageGrid.bannerName | noUnderscore }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this?

```js
{{imageGrid.bannerName.replace('_', ' ')}}
```

ok the correct solution needs to add a flag 'g'

```
{{imageGrid.bannerName.replace(/_/g, ' ')}}
```

Comment: This statement replaces just the first (not every) occurrence.

Comment: I tried but its replaced first one. Output : DINING LANDING_PAGE_MEAL_PLAN_UNSUBSCRIBED_USER

Comment: use g modifier to perform a global match also

`{{imageGrid.bannerName.replace(/_/g, ' ')}}`

Comment: {{imageGrid.bannerName.replace(/_/g, ' ')}} - Not working

Answer (score 2):

“DINING_LANDING_PAGE_MEAL_PLAN_SUBSCRIBED_USER”.split(“_”).join(“ “)

Comment: Solves the need of regex, nice

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom pipe if you are using Angular V2+

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
/*
 * Replace the underscore with space 
*/
@Pipe({name: 'underscore'})
export class UnderscorePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    return  value.replace(/\_/g, ' ');
  }
}
```

This pipe has to be declared in your module. i.e., `AppModule.ts`

```
import { UnderscorePipe } from './underscore.pipe';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UnderscorePipe
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In the HTML side

```
{{imageGrid.bannerName | underscore}}
```

If you would like to have a more sophisticated pipe, we can pass the parameter

Custom pipe implementation

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
/*
 * Replace the the first paremeter with the second parameter 
*/
@Pipe({name: 'replace'})
export class ReplacePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, existing: string, latest: string): string {
    return  value.replace(new RegExp('\\'+existing, 'g'), latest);
  }
}
```

HTML file

```
 <h2>Hi Please {{value | replace: '_' : ' '}}</h2>
```